# Create a dynamic accordion menu. More info below

Tags: php, wordpress, dynamic, accordion

I need to create a dynamic accordion menu for Wordpress that gets fed it's information from a database(or the "Menu's" tab in Wordpress). The menu will have three levels and all levels will be closed on the homepage and when, for example, a user clicks on 'Contact' they should be taken to the contact page and only then will 'Contact' expand to show the second levels of the menu. I hope you understand. I need examples and details on how to do this from start to finish.

Answer (score 2):

That's not a simple question and without your sample code, no one knows what you're really trying to do. Try searching for existing plugins http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=jquery+menu&sort= and http://www.google.com/search?&q=jquery+menu+wordpress&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8 and look at the code.